# How to get the Chandrasekhar Limit from a plot?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, stellar-physics, white-dwarfs

[image: Radius vs. Mass]

at the moment I am trying to understand, how to obtain the Chandrasekhar mass limit from a plot like shown above.

Because for $n$ = 3, the mass is independent of the radius of the white dwarf.
But in the green line, I see a dependence, which I do not understand.
So do you have a formula to get a plot like in the picture?

And I am also interested, on how to find the Chandrasekhar mass numerically by solving the Lane-Emden equation (what I did already).

Best regards,

Tobias

Comment: The [English Wiki page on white dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf#Mass%E2%80%93radius_relationship_and_mass_limit) outlines how the limit comes about. See also [Chandrasekhar's WD Wiki entry as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar%27s_white_dwarf_equation)

Comment: Yeah but I need the equation, where the plot comes from.

Comment: Your link does not work for me. Please put the picture in your post. If you are talking about the mass-radius relationship for cold electrons, there is no (accurate) analytic formula for it.

Comment: @RobJeffries ok, done.
Yes, it is the mass-radius relationship. But if there is no analytic formula, how could they plot it?

Comment: By plotting the results of numerical solutions to the equations of stellar structure.

Answer (score 1):

To find the mass-radius relationship for a (non-rotating) star in general you solve the equations for hydrostatic equilibrium (Newtonian for white dwarfs, general relativistic for neutron stars) with an equation of state $\epsilon(P)$, which relates energy density to pressure. You can then find the mass through
$$ M(r) = \int_0^r dr \ 4\pi r^2\epsilon(r),$$
which is the mass contained within the radius $r$. The mass $M = M(R)$ of a given star (of radius $R$ can be parametrized by the energy density at the center $\epsilon_c = \epsilon(0)$. It can then be shown that stable stars are those that obey
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial\epsilon_c} \geq 0.$$
Thus, the limiting mass of a star is a local maximum of the mass as a function of central density (if it was a local minimum the star could get more massive and still be stable). The solution to the hydrostatic equilibrium equations also allows you to determine the mass-radius relationship, and with the knowledge of what the limiting mass is, this tells you what the radius of the largest mass star subject to that equation of state.

As was commented, except for extremely special models, which need not be at all accurate to what we observe, the mass-radius relationship has no analytic form. But that doesn't mean it can't be plotted. You said yourself that you numerically solved the Lane-Emden equation. That's not an analytic solution but you can still plot it. In general, for a white dwarf with a polytropic equation of state, one approach is to solve the Lane-Emden equation, take your solution and put it back into physical variables, and then follow the procedure I mentioned above that tells you what the maximum mass is.

With a plot like you have in the question, you can just read off the maximum mass as the largest mass on the curve. You (should) know that the largest mass white dwarfs have relativistic electrons, so look at that branch for the largest mass and you see it's around 1.4 solar masses.

Comment: Thank you very much.
But for the Lane-Emden equation, the mass-radius relation is independent of the radius for the ultrarelativistic case, so I am not able to make a plot like on the picture just with that knowledge, right?

Comment: The important thing to note here is that "relativistic" doesn't always mean "ultrarelativistic". Just look at the black line labeled "ultrarelativistic". That line is the result of the mass being independent of radius. The curve labeled "relativistic" is a result of being more careful, and treating the equation of state in a more accurate manner, using the relativistic energy. In general you would have to find the equation of state numerically and then use that to numerically solve the equilibrium equations and then obtain the mass-radius relation from that.